# Is this proper notation: $\;\mathbb Z^{+-}\;$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a question about notation. Is it okay to represent $\;\mathbb Z^{+-}$ as $ \mathbb Z - \{0\}$ ?

Like does it make sense to manipulate both sets mathematically like that? ) i.e. $ \{0\} = \mathbb Z - \mathbb Z^{-+} $

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use the second one. I have never seen the first notation before, to be honest :)

Comment: Using the minus for set difference (i.e. $X - Y$ as an alternative notation for $X \setminus Y$) is widespread. Unless you mix it with $A - B = \{ a - b \colon a \in A, b \in B \}$, there's no problem.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply fellas. have a good one.

Comment: sorry about that. didn't mean anything by it.

Answer (score 11):

Using $\mathbb Z^{+-}$ would have given me little clue as to what you are denoting, were it not for the equality you use to define it. (Okay, I could have probably guessed, but why make your readers have to guess?)

I would strictly use $ \mathbb Z - \{0\}$, or better yet, $\mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$. I'd even prefer it were spelled out in words: "all non-zero integers" than trying to guess what your notation denotes. (I have never seen the notation $\mathbb Z^{+-},\,$ to be honest.)

I don't think it makes sense to write $ \{0\}$ as $\mathbb Z - \mathbb Z^{-+} $. (I'm not clear why you'd want to avoid using $\{0\})$. In any case, using $\;\{0\}$ is much more straightforward, and easier to write and read.

Comment: noted for future reference!

Comment: Always good to ask, when in doubt! :-)

Answer (score 5):

The notation $\Bbb Z^{+-}$ is confusing. I'd probably write $\Bbb Z_0$ for $\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. While there are several meanings for the notation for $\Bbb Z_n$ when $n\neq 0$, there are none (that I am aware of) in the case of $n=0$.

Of course you can, and should, always define clearly new symbols that you are using.

---

As Rahul suggests in the comments, a much better idea is to use $\Bbb Z_{\neq0}$ or $\Bbb Z^{\neq0}$, this instantly tells you what is the content of the set.

Comment: I'd suggest $\mathbb Z_{\ne0}$, which makes it totally clear. I always prefer when people write $\mathbb R_{\ge0}$ or $\mathbb R_{>0}$ instead of $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: @Rahul: I totally agree. I'm going to steal this idea and add it into my answer!

Comment: I've seen those superscripted as well, sometims. @RahulNarain Such as: $\mathbb R^{\geq 0}$. In algebra with fields, of course, $\mathbb k^*$ is the non-zero elements of $k$, but that doesn't work with non-fields.

Comment: @Thomas: I actually had an instinct to write $\Bbb Z^\times$, but that one is the units, which in a field means non-zero elements, but in $\Bbb Z$ means only $\pm1$...

Answer (score 2):

For your own purposes you can use any notation, but it probably wouldn't be understood by others without qualification. $\mathbb{Z}^*$ stands for the set of invertible integers, while $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ means integers except zero. Personally I'd simply write $\mathbb{Z}\setminus 0$, or if you prefer more rigorously $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Or just "nonzero integers".

Answer (score -1):

$\Bbb{Z}-\{0\}$ is usually denoted by $\Bbb{Z}^*$, the set of invertible integers.

Comment: Only $\pm1$ are invertible.

Comment: I was confusing $\mathbb Z^{-+}$ with $\mathbb Z^* $ that's the one that the math department at my university uses.

Comment: In France,$\mathbb{Z}^*$ sometimes means $\mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$, and sometimes $\{+1, -1\}$, we never know.

Comment: @justt: One more reason to study probability well. You can calculate the probability of it being one or the other! Then you can say that a certain statement is true in probability $p$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm referring to $\Bbb{Z}$ as a subring of $\Bbb{R}$ so *invertible* means *invertible in $\Bbb{R}$*

Comment: Ah. Your answer didn't say that, and I left my mind reading cap in my other pants...